# BC30311 Value of type 'Rectangle' cannot be converted to 'Rectangle' error in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, printing

I have seen many tutorials to get get print dataGridView and also download a project that is working fine but when I try it into my own project I got the error
BC30311 Value of type 'Rectangle' cannot be converted to 'Rectangle'

```
Private bitmap As Bitmap
    Private Sub BtnPrintCS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrintCS.Click
        'Resize DataGridView to full height.
        Dim height As Integer = DataLockersList.Height
        DataLockersList.Height = DataLockersList.RowCount * DataLockersList.RowTemplate.Height
        'Dim widDoc As Integer = Me.DataLockersList.Width
        'Dim higDoc As Integer = Me.DataLockersList.Height
        'Dim rectangle1 As New Rectangle(0, 0, widDoc, higDoc)
        'Create a Bitmap and draw the DataGridView on it.
        bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.DataLockersList.Width, Me.DataLockersList.Height)

        DataLockersList.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.DataLockersList.Width, Me.DataLockersList.Height))

        'Resize DataGridView back to original height.
        DataLockersList.Height = height

        'Show the Print Preview Dialog.
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        'Print the contents.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Switch Option Explicit and Option Strict on and also check that the Rectangle you're creating is from the expected namespace of the DrawToBitmap method.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer How to check the Rectangle you're creating is from the expected namespace of the DrawToBitmap method.